# Using both $L_2$ regularization and early stopping when training ANN's

Tags: self-study, neural-networks, regularization

I came across an ANN that's used for approximating a noisy sine function. On one hand it uses a validation set for early stopping, and then again uses the same validation set for fine tuning the regularization parameter. I wondered if this was a legit approach and common practice because of two reasons:

1. I thought early stopping itself was a form of regularization, isn't it then redundant to use both a regularization parameter and early stopping?
2. If one were to take this approach wouldn't it be better to two different validation sets? One for the early stopping and one for fine tuning the regularization parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It is 'redundant'. Early stopping essentially works because the weights start small, and $L_2$ regularization tries to keep them small. However, you are using gradient descent,  so it's pretty random, and you are reduced to trial and error aka cross validation.
2. Using the same validation set sounds fine - you are cross validating the double parameter (stopping time, $L_2$ regularization). Obviously better to do k-fold cross validation than using single validation set.